# smooth vector field on the boundary of unit ball

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let C be the boundary of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $v$ be a smooth vector field on $C$. What does the condition $x\cdot v(x)>0$ for all $x$ in C mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your vector field is pointing outwards.

Obs: One can conclude from here that if $v$ is extended to the whole ball $B$ then it will be zero at at least one point inside.

Comment: Can I ask how you tell it is pointing outwards? What does that dot product mean?

Comment: The dot product $w\cdot v$ is $||w|| \cdot ||v|| \cdot \cos \angle(w,v)$. If the dot product is positive then the angle is between $0$ and $\pi/2$. If it was $\pi/2$ (the angle between the radius $x$ and $v(x)$ then $v(x)$ would be tangent to the sphere. If the angle were $>\pi/2$ ( cosine $< 0,$ or dot product $< 0$) then it would point inwards. The threshold value is $\pi/2$ when the dot product is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $v$ is tangent to the sphere, if you consider $\phi_t$ its flow, $\|\phi_t\|^2=1$ by differentiating that you have $<x,v(x)>=0$. So $<x,v(x)>$ can't be >0.